# JCR 170 Data modeling: Node names

Tags: java, data-modeling, jackrabbit, jcr

**The situation:**
Lets say we are implementing a blog engine based on JCR with support for localization.
The content structure looks something like this */blogname/content/[node name]*

**The problem:**
What is the best way to name the content nodes (/blogname/content/**[nodename]**) to satisfy the following requirements:

1. The node name must be usable in HTML to support REST like URLs i.e.: blogname.com/content/nodename should point to a single content item.
2. The above requirement must not produce ugly URLs i.e.: /content/node_name is good, /content/node%20name is bad.
3. Programmatic retrieval should be easy given the node name i.e.: //content[@node_name=some-name]
4. The naming scheme must guarantee node name uniqueness.

PS: The JCR implementation used is [JackRabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

**For 1. to 3. the answer is simple:** just use characters you want to see in the node name, ie. escape whatever input string you have (eg. the blog post title) against a restricted character set such as [the one for URIs](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt).

For example, do not allow spaces (which are allowed for JCR node names, but would produce the ugly `%20` in URLs) and other chars that must be encoded in URLs. You can remove those chars or simply replace them with a underscore, because that looks good in most cases.

**Regarding unique names (4.)**, you can either include the current time incl. milliseconds into it or you explicitly check for collisions. The first might look a bit ugly, but should probably never fail for a blog scenario. The latter can be done by reacting upon the exception thrown if a node with such a name already exists and adding eg. an incrementing counter and try again (eg. `my_great_post1`, `my_great_post2`, etc.). You can also lock the parent node so that only one session can actually add a node at the same time, which avoids a trial loop, but comes at the cost of blocking.

**Note:** `//content[@node_name=some-name]` is not a valid JCR Xpath query. You probably want to use `/jcr:root/content//some-name` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding item 3. I recently learned that xpath queries do not allow items to start with a number.  If your node name starts with a number it can still be queried by escaping the first byte of the name, but your queries will be more straightforward if you start all node names with a letter.

(I'm not sure about property names.  Haven't ever seen one that didn't start with a letter.)

Answer (score 0):

Unique names: To quickly generate a unique name from the first characters of a title plus a random number (to resolve conflicts), you could use the following algorithm:

```
String title = "JCR 170 Data modeling: Node names";
String name = title.substring(0, Math.min(title.length(), 10)).trim().replace(' ', '_');
if (name is not unique) {
    name += "_";
    Random r = new Random();
    while (name is not unqiue) {
        name += Integer.toString(r.nextInt(10));
    }
}
```

The advantage to use a random number is: even if you have many similar names, this will resolve conflicts very quickly.